# what's the difference between 'localhost' and '127.0.0.1'?

Tags: localhost

There is a nginx server listen on 8080 port, and telnet with localhost and 127.0.0.1. One connected, one connected fail otherwise.

```
[test@localhost sbin]$ telnet localhost 8080          
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused

[test@localhost sbin]$ telnet 127.0.0.1 8080
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

What's the difference between 'localhost' and '127.0.0.1'?Why localhost connect fail?Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

`127.0.0.1` is the IPv4 address to the local machine.

`localhost` is a name that is looked up to find the addresses of the local machine. In your case it finds the IPv6 address first (::1) and tries to connect to that. If your service is only listening on IPv4, it will fail to connect.

Comment: ::1 should be embraced by []-->[::1]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that localhost is bound to ipv6 and you are not listening on ::1 ipv6 IP.

Answer (score 0):

Localhost is the naming address of the ip address 127.0.0.1
It is not possible to remember ip address that's why computer use dns means Domain Name System (DNS) .It convert naming to ip address as well as reverse.
An often-used analogy to explain the Domain Name System is that it serves as the phone book for the Internet by translating human-friendly computer hostnames into IP addresses. For example, the domain name www.example.com translates to the addresses 93.184.216.119 (IPv4) and 2606:2800:220:6d:26bf:1447:1097:aa7 (IPv6).

Answer (score 0):

Hostnames can resolve to both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. `"localhost" resolves to IPv4 (127.0.0.1) and IPv6 [::1].`

For this use-case, localhost finds the IPv6 address `(from Trying ::1...)` which results in connection fail as your service is listing to IPv4

I think Windows' preference is to use IPv6 where possible, which is why localhost defaults to the IPv6 resolution. If you turned off IPv6 it would go to the IPv4 address.

Apart from this, the reason is that many ISPs don't provide customers with IPv6 addresses (and many routers/modems can't handle them), and you need all devices in a chain to use IPv6 if you want to reach a server using IPv6.